# Unpublishing components - en masse

Tags: 2011, publishing

Can't believe I've never had to do this before, but I need to unpublish approx 1500 components - unlike structure groups I cant just right-click there is no such option for folders.

We're using Fredhopper so this is important as I need the unpublish to go through the publishing extension that will instruct Fredhopper to drop its reference as well.

I tried to use a Virtual Folder/Saved Search and tweak the number of items setting - `<NumberOfItems>1500</NumberOfItems>` - to give me a complete list I could then select all on but this always gives me a timeout error.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Any idea if the timeout is related to your search collection maintenance? Maybe rebuilding the index would help?

Comment: Why can't you choose the templates of the components and un-publish the template?

Comment: I think that maybe my best option Pankaj - its just that there are 15 - 20 templates marked as dynamic and I wanted a more direct way to just list all published components.

Comment: Thanks Nuno - so in theory should the search be able to return over 500 items? I ask this because thats the default in the GUI.

Comment: Very good question. I am pretty sure the default is just there to prevent "regular" users from creating search folders with 10.000 items in it - overriding the default in the Search Folder definition used to work for sure in the 5.x days, I would expect it to still work today.

Comment: This use case begs for a PowerShell script. it's a bit powerful than improvising through the gui, and no 'real' programming needed. Are you trying to unpublish ask dynamic components from all targets?

Comment: Jan - yes. I've ended up taking Pankaj advice and simply unpublish from via Component Templates (something I forgot about :p).

Answer (score 4):

If you're using SDL Tridion 2013 you can use the bundles feature to publish / un-publish the components you need as one transaction.

The [official bundle documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/task_652A1F15538F40C098828428AD6815BE) (log on required) is thin, but explains that it's perfectly possible